# Can plug-in electromagnetic pest control devices repel rodents?

Tags: pesticides

On the [Pest Free web site](https://www.pestfree.com.au/) they claim they can control pests with an electromagnetic device.

> Plug-in Pest Free is electronic pest control device that uses small, completely safe, pulses of electro magnetic force to repell pests such as rodents, rats, mice and aids in the control of cockroaches. Unlike other methods of pest control, Pest Free uses no chemicals, fumes or toxic materials, meaning all Pest Free devices are a form of completely natural pest control.

Is there any scientific backing to Electromagnetic pulse pest control for rodents?

Comment: It would be extraordinary if a store claimed their products do not work.